# Error trying to create a new vm in ansible

Tags: vmware-esxi, ansible, vmware-vcenter, ansible-playbook

I just started learning Ansible. It has been a pain so far. I have this code to create a new vm. I followed this [tutorial.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html)

```
    ---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
            vcenter_hostname:1.1.1.12
            username: root
            password: pasword
            guest: newvm001
            state: powered_on
            validate_certs: no
            vm_extra_config:
                vcpu.hotadd: yes
                mem.hotadd:  yes
                notes: This is a test VM
                folder: MyFolder
            vm_disk:
                disk1:
                        size_gb: 10
                        type: thin
                        datastore: storage001
            vm_nic:
                nic1:
                    type: vmxnet3
                    network: VM Network
                    network_type: standard
            vm_hardware:
                memory_mb: 256
                num_cpus: 1
                osid: ubuntu64Guest
                scsi: paravirtual
            esxi:
                datacenter: 1.1.1.12
                hostname: 1.1.1.12
```

I however keep getting this error.

> [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts
>
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
>
> PLAY [localhost]
>
> TASK [setup]
>   ******************************************************************* ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [vsphere_guest]
>   *********************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":
>   "Cannot find datacenter named: 9.1.142.86"}
>
> NO MORE HOSTS LEFT
>   ************************************************************* [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'testing.retry'. [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory: ''
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************* localhost : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1

Why is that so? What is a datacenter? How can i find the appropriate datacenter to use? And what is the difference between a host file and an inventory file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one major problem and one minor problem.

First, the major problem: You haven't supplied the correct `datacenter` name.

```
            esxi:
                datacenter: 1.1.1.12
```

This is supposed to be set to the name of the Datacenter object in vSphere. (And, as specified in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html), it should be set to `ha-datacenter` if you're talking to a standalone ESXi host.)

The minor problem is that you've used IP addresses rather than hostnames for connection information. What to do about this is obvious.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a million. We don't have a datacenter for  the host  so i was supposed to use ha-datacenter. And i fixed the ip address problem too